# GetMember vs GetField performance in C#

Tags: c#, performance, reflection

Anybody know what the best to use to read a XmlEnumAttribute

Option 1: With GetMember

```
    public static string XmlEnum(this Enum e)
    {
        Type type = e.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(e.ToString());
        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlEnumAttribute), false);
            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                return ((XmlEnumAttribute)attrs[0]).Name;
            }
        }
        return e.ToString();
    }
```

Option 2: With GetField

```
    public static string XmlEnum2(this Enum e)
    {
        Type type = e.GetType();
        FieldInfo info = type.GetField(e.ToString());
        if (!info.IsDefined(typeof(XmlEnumAttribute), false))
        {
            return e.ToString();
        }
        object[] attrs = info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlEnumAttribute), false);
        return ((XmlEnumAttribute)attrs[0]).Name;
    }
```

Comment: Why not try 100,000 times and see how long it takes in each case?

Comment: Whichever is faster, it's unlikely to make a measurable difference in any program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why not try 100,000 times and see how long it takes in each case?

Because that doesn't test a realistic usage scenario for an attribute.  It is expensive the *first* time you dig up an attribute, cheap after that.  The expense is loading the IL for the attribute class and compiling it, locating the attribute data in the assembly metadata and loading it from disk.  Then calling the attribute constructor and assigning the attribute properties.  The cost of your code to read the attribute is peanuts compared to that, it's the disk I/O that's expensive by several orders of magnitude.  The second time you retrieve the attribute, a lot of that work is done and it will be quick, just the object initialization from data that's cached.

You normally read an attribute only once, maybe a few times.  So the cost is dominated by the expensive first time, the code you use matters very little.  Go ahead and profile it.  Just make sure you don't treat that expensive first time as "experimental error".